# i get the following error ;undefined variable, in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Controller**
when i run the code i get the error : 
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: controllers/User.php

Line Number: 293

```
public function edit()
    {
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('Users_model');
    $this->load->model('Images_model');
    $this->load->view('edit');
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$id);

    }
```

**model**

```
public function edit($data,$id)
    {
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->update('user',$data); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you haven't defined `$id` anywhere in your `controller`, if you want to use the `id` in the `controller` then you must define it. Now since you're editing something you must send it via `URL`-

```
public function edit($id = false) // default value is null if you don't provide anything in your URL
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('Users_model');
    $this->load->model('Images_model');
    $this->load->view('edit');
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $id);

}
```

Hope this helps you. :)